# На чём основан HashMap, что из себя представляют бакеты?

Tags: java, java-hashmap, hashmap

Здраствуйте, вопрос вроде простой, но внятный ответ найти не смог. И так: из коллекций Java я усвоил, что они основываются либо на массивах, либо на взаимоссылках. Всё понятно. Про HM везде объяснение начинается с "вот есть бакеты/корзины"..."которые хранят пару ключ-значение"..."вот есть несколько бакетов"... и т.д. Что из себя представляет бакет (объект с полями К-З, массив, лист?)? Как хранятся эти бакеты (Массив бакетов, лист бакетов?)? Вот в общем и весь вопрос. Дальше про механизм работы мне всё понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: в зависимости от версии джавы. раньше это был обычный двусвязный список, т.е. linkedlist. т.е. по хешу вы ищите бакет со сложностью о(1), а дальше все, что в одном бакете (случаи коллизии) простым перебором, т.е. сложность о(n). для понимания этого думаю достаточно (по крайней мере для начала).

Comment: если линклист, то у него скорость поиска O(n), там же надо по ссылкам идти к нужному объекту?

Comment: все верно, а я как написал? до бакета по хешу о(1), а внутри бакета, т.е. по самому линкедлисту, о(n)

Comment: Ок, а бакеты-то как хранятся? В виде какой структуры?

Comment: третий раз : бакеты - это линкедлист

Comment: В третий раз, где лежат бакеты?

Comment: бакеты связаны с хешированной таблицей и представляют собой линкедлист, ключом которой является хешкод. в итоге имеем соответствие хешкод-бакет. таким образом бакеты ищем по хешу (это достигается с помощью хешированной таблицы), а после этого паопадаем в линкедлист и там ищем простым перебором (в случае, если есть коллизия, иначе там 1 элемент).

Comment: @Дмитрий, не называйте список в бакете LinkedList'ом. Потому что там не эта структура данных. Там односвязанный список. Загляните во внутрь HashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Да, правильно, **массив** бакетов
- Но в бакетах не LinkedList, а односвязанный список, в котором есть ссылки только на next node
- Односвязанный список меняется на красно-черное бинарное дерево при достижении количества его элементов 8 (TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8) и обратно при уменьшении кол-ва элементов до 6 (UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6)

Comment: понял, ввела в заблуждение следующая картинка: https://cdn.javarush.ru/images/article/b63dec6a-24d0-4f85-bbe4-2b609f2c9eb4/800.webp. Отличие односвязного списка от ЛинкедЛист - то, что ссылка у узла есть только на следующий узел? Я так понял. Большое спасибо за ёмкий ответ, кстати.

Comment: @ДенисКондратов, да, принципиальное отличие от двусвязанного списка в этом. Но вообще это другая структура данных, другой класс. В HashMap список в бакете это java.util.HashMap.Node.

Answer (score 1):

Всё разобрался, бакеты - это ячейки в обычном массиве которые представляют собой линклисты(с переходом в дерево при определенных условиях). Т.е. хэшмап, упрощённо, массив линклистов.

Comment: Если под "линклист" подрозумевается LinkedList, то это не так. Там не LinkedList. Там односвязанный список.